# Magento2 Add new field in product attribute edit form

Tags: php, xml, magento2

I want to add new dropdown field in product attribute edit/new form page. I have created a module with ui_component file but my new field is not showing on the page, no errors as site is in developer mode.

These are my module files:

```
app/code/Vendor/Grouping/registration.php
    <?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Grouping',
    __DIR__
);

app/code/Vendor/Grouping/etc/module.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Grouping" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
    </module>
</config>

app/code/Vendor/Grouping/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_attribute_add_form.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
     <fieldset name="base_fieldset">
         <field name="layered_group">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Inputtype</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">22</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">product_attribute</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Layered Nav Attribute Group</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">frontend_input</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
     </fieldset>
</form>
```

In this file `product_attribute_add_form.xml` file i duplicate the `frontend_input` and change field name and labels.

How to add this new field in this form?

Comment: Can you please share your code?I also want same as you.

Comment: Hey @SnehaPanchal, I was able add the new filed with event observer. just like Magento Layered navigation module does: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/LayeredNavigation/etc/adminhtml/events.xml#L9. and https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/LayeredNavigation/Observer/Edit/Tab/Front/ProductAttributeFormBuildFrontTabObserver.php#L40

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`?

You need to run it to update `add/etc/config.php`. Your module has to be placed after Magento_Catalog.

Comment: Thanks Igor, i run these commands before but noting worked. Finally i was able to add this field with product_attribute_form_build_front_tab event/observer.